# How should this site's general chat room be named?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

The [general chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69396/iota) for this new site is called iota. Now that's quite boring.

So, how should the main chat room be named? It is custom to use a clever play of words on the topic of the site.

Comment: IOTA protocol Ecosystem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another one:

> The Soon™ Room

Comment: Plenty of interesting ideas... I'll wait for some more community votes to come in before accepting one.

Comment: Soon™? ;-p *grin*

Comment: Exactly ;) or as we say at IoT: *right away*

Comment: That is nice...

Comment: A variation on the theme is *Soon™ Saloon* :-)

Comment: *Soon Saloon* has a certain ring to it!

Answer (score 2):

What about:

> The Tangle Hub

Or:

> Weight Magnitude 14

Answer (score 1):

Chatiota
Iotalk
TangleTalk
Iotanglement

Comment: I like IoTalk a lot. It's clear what it is, unlike a lot of other suggestions, which are a bit too cliquey.

Comment: + 1 for Chatiota and IoTalk

Answer (score 0):

> ReTangle

Or

> "Frozen Pizza Discussions"

Answer (score 0):

> EnTangled

referring to Tangle, means 'caught in'

or

> UnHashed
>
> Curled

referring to Curl Hash function

Answer (score -1):

What about:

> Megaiota Megalomaniacs

Answer (score -2):

How do you like

> WOON PALACE